# Get nth child of an ul using cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

i am trying to scrape amazon books using `Cheerio` and `request` in `nodeJS`

But i can't figure how to get `Print length` and `publication date` from `HTML` code below

```
<table id="productDetailsTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="bucket">
        <h2>Product Details</h2>
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <b>File Size:</b>
              2544 KB
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Print Length:</b>
              658 pages
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Publisher:</b>
              Anchor; 1st edition (September 15, 2009)
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: i couldn't properly indent this HTML. sorry for that.

Comment: #productDetailsTable ul li:nth-child(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adapting the approaches in [cheerio: Get normal + text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878673/cheerio-get-normal-text-nodes/73693773#73693773) and [How to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags in Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690939/how-to-get-a-text-thats-separated-by-different-html-tags-in-cheerio/73692854#73692854). The `.content()` method gives normal and text nodes:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = [...$("#productDetailsTable .bucket .content li")].map(e =>
  [...$(e).contents()]
    .map(e => $(e).text().trim())
    .filter(Boolean)
);
console.log(result);
```

Which gives:

```js
[
  [ 'File Size:', '2544 KB' ],
  [ 'Print Length:', '658 pages' ],
  [ 'Publisher:', 'Anchor; 1st edition (September 15, 2009)' ]
]
```

Consider also

```js
const obj = Object.fromEntries(result.map(([a, b]) => [a.slice(0, -1), b]));
```

which produces:

```js
{
  'File Size:': '2544 KB',
  'Print Length:': '658 pages',
  'Publisher:': 'Anchor; 1st edition (September 15, 2009)'
}
```

If you need the publication date specifically, try:

```js
console.log(obj.Publisher.match(/(?<=\().+(?=\))/g)[0]);
```

which prints `September 15, 2009`.