# Getting specific text from an XML element in cheerio with multiple tags

Tags: node.js, cheerio

using cheerio to parse XML, I am trying to get only the user readable description from the tag. I.E.

```
<description><![CDATA[<p><img src="https://www.boxingnews24.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Gervonta-Davis-vs-Ryan-Garcia1-Boxing-Photos.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 1em auto"></p>
<p>By <strong>Sam Volz:</strong> *****Eddie Hearn views it as positive if Ryan Garcia teams up with his former trainer Eddy Reynoso to try and pick up***** &#8230; <a href="https://www.boxingnews24.com/2023/05/eddie-hearn-reacts-to-ryan-garcia-possibly-linking-up-with-reynoso/" class="read-more">read full story &#8592; </a></p>
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.boxingnews24.com/2023/05/eddie-hearn-reacts-to-ryan-garcia-possibly-linking-up-with-reynoso/">Eddie Hearn reacts to Ryan Garcia possibly linking up with Reynoso</a>  @  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.boxingnews24.com">Boxing News 24</a></p>
]]></description>
```

I have wrapped the text I want to retrieve with multiple "*". Without specific class attritbutes, I am unsure how to grab this since there are multiple p tags as well. Just want to add I am new to cheerio.

For clarity the text I want to retrieve is "Eddie Hearn views it as positive if Ryan Garcia teams up with his former trainer Eddy Reynoso to try and pick up"

Comment: Sorry--what output are you expecting and why? Could you share your code so far? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I have added the text I wanted to retrieve. As of now I am just finding the description tag and pulling out the text.

Comment: Ah right you had that clear--but what's the pattern here that we're looking for? Just the first `<p>` tag, but only whatever comes after the `<strong>` tag? You can probably use `.contents()` to do this, like in [cheerio: Get normal + text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878673/cheerio-get-normal-text-nodes/73693773#73693773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code returns the result you want for this specific input, but it's not clear to me whether we can rely on the presence of the `<strong>` and ordering of the child notes within your `<p>` for this to work on other cases. Without having some description of how we're supposed to identify this text in general, I've naively assumed that the text we want is the third child:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const xml = `<description><![CDATA[<p><img src="https://www.boxingnews24.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Gervonta-Davis-vs-Ryan-Garcia1-Boxing-Photos.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 1em auto"></p>
<p>By <strong>Sam Volz:</strong> *****Eddie Hearn views it as positive if Ryan Garcia teams up with his former trainer Eddy Reynoso to try and pick up***** &#8230; <a href="https://www.boxingnews24.com/2023/05/eddie-hearn-reacts-to-ryan-garcia-possibly-linking-up-with-reynoso/" class="read-more">read full story &#8592; </a></p>
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.boxingnews24.com/2023/05/eddie-hearn-reacts-to-ryan-garcia-possibly-linking-up-with-reynoso/">Eddie Hearn reacts to Ryan Garcia possibly linking up with Reynoso</a>  @  <a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.boxingnews24.com">Boxing News 24</a></p>
]]></description>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(xml, {xml: true});
console.log($($.load($("description").text())("p").contents()[3]).text());
```