# Get image from figure tag using cheerio on xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, cheerio, cdata

I am trying to extract the img src from the following xml tag inside of an item

I am calling cheerio.load on my response data like so

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data, { xmlMode: true });
    $("item").each((i, item) => {
```

and I am coming across this specific tag in item that I want to extract the img src from

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large">
<img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="800" height="572" src="http://wmcmuaythai.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WhatsApp-Image-2023-04-07-at-3.18.13-PM-2-800x572.jpeg" alt="" class="wp-image-43535" srcset="http://wmcmuaythai.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WhatsApp-Image-2023-04-07-at-3.18.13-PM-2-800x572.jpeg 800w, http://wmcmuaythai.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WhatsApp-Image-2023-04-07-at-3.18.13-PM-2-350x250.jpeg 350w, http://wmcmuaythai.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WhatsApp-Image-2023-04-07-at-3.18.13-PM-2-768x549.jpeg 768w, http://wmcmuaythai.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/WhatsApp-Image-2023-04-07-at-3.18.13-PM-2.jpeg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 800px) 100vw, 800px" />
</figure>
```

I have tried the following cheerio queries and either keep getting undefined or not what I want.

```
$(item).find("figure").find("img").attr("src")
$(item).find("img").attr("src")
$(item).find("figure").children().find("img").attr("src")
$(item).find("figure").first().find("img").attr("src")
```

This is the rss feed in which I am trying to extract the figure from

http://wmcmuaythai.org/feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with XML but the tags you want look like they're inside CDATA. I've [had success in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76178486/6243352) by loading the CDATA text into Cheerio, then traversing that inner structure.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

fetch("<Your URL>")
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  })
  .then(html => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xml: true});
    const result = [...$("content\\:encoded")].flatMap(e =>
      [...$.load($(e).text())("img")].map(e => $(e).attr("src"))
    );
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.length); // => 51
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You may want to unflatten the map to maintain the groupings, depending on whatever your expected result is.

Comment: Ive had success selecting content:encoded by using $(item).find("content\\:encoded"). However, I will try a variation of your answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I should have tried that. Updated. Does this work for you?

Comment: It does work! However, is there a way to only grab 1 per item? As of now grabbing the first item from each array works fine. But I feel it is inefficient to be grabbing an array of an arbritrary size to just grab the first value.

Comment: Does `[...$("content\\:encoded")].map(e => $.load($(e).text())("img").first().attr("src"));` work, assuming you want the first? I wouldn't worry much about efficiency unless the XML file is massive.

Comment: Also, while I'm at it, did [my other answer to your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76178486/6243352) work for you?

Comment: Not quite. It is still passing an array of images

Comment: I actually realized the format in which description is passed has too much variability per XML so I put it in the back burner for now.

Comment: Oh, you want just one single image for the whole document? `$.load($("content\\:encoded").first().text())("img").first().attr("src")`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I have learned a lot from you alone hahah.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$("img", item)` selector to find the img tag within the item element and then use the `.attr("src")`

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data, { xml: true });

$("item").each((i, item) => {
  const imgSrc = $("img", item).attr("src");
  console.log(imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: I just tried this but keep receiving undefined.

Comment: try $(item).find('figure > img').attr('src') it may work

Comment: Still getting undefined sadly :(

Comment: if you getting undefined then it is possible that the Cheerio selector is not finding the img tag inside the figure tag. You have to debug check $(item).find('figure').html()  and $(item).find('figure > img').length this will return number of img tag

Comment: I have tried both of those and received null and 0. For context I have attached the RSS feed in which I am receiving my xml. I have also noticed there is a specific tag "content:encoded" that also contains the figure and img. I have successfully found the content:encoded tag but cannot go further and grab the figure/img.

Comment: if you able to get content:encoded then use below code to grab img tag

$(item).find('content\\:encoded').each((i, el) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load($(el).text(), { xmlMode: true });
  const src = $('figure > img').attr('src');
  console.log(src);
});

Comment: I feel I am getting closer with your help, but it still is not working.